# Use ForkJoin and Map together to get all pages of a paged API Endpoint

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to be able to call an API that returns a page of data as many times as is required to get all of the data, and then return the concatenated result as an observable. At the same time, I'd like to map the result to select a subset of the properties returned.

The first thing I'm doing is calling the API to get the first page AND the total number of pages. I'm then using the total number of pages to determine how many additional API calls I need to make.  I then construct an array of observables and call them using forkJoin.

The problem I'm having is that forkjoin returns an observable, but I'm calling it from within a map function. As a result, my method then attempts to return an Observable of an Observable. I need to somehow return the result of the observable. I tried to find a way to use subscribe instead of map on the forkJoin result, but then my method doesn't await for the forkJoin results to emit.

How do I get the result of an observable and return it from the map?

```
public getData(): Observable<PartialResponse[]> {

    // get page 1
    this.getPagedData(1, maxPageSize).map((firstResponse: PagedDataResponse) => {
        let pgCt: number = firstResponse.totalPages;
        let result: PartialResponse[];

        //uses lodash to map the response to partialResponse
        result = _.map(firstResponse.data, ((r: FullResponse) => {
            return new PartialResponse(r.property1, r.property2);
        }));

        // create an array of observations for getting additional pages
        let additionalRequests = new Array<Observable<PagedDataResponse>>();
        if (pgCt > 1) {
            for (var i = 2; i <= pgCt; i++) {
                additionalRequests.push(this.getPagedData(i, maxPageSize));
            }
        }

        Observable.forkJoin(additionalRequests).map((datasets: IPagedData<AdministrationDto>[]) => {
            for (let responseX of datasets) {
                pgCt = responseX.totalPages;
                result = result.concat(_.map(responseX.data, ((r: FullResponse) => {
                    return new PartialResponse(r.property1, r.property2);
                })));
            }
            return result;
        });
    });
```

}

Comment: Your code is wrong so it makes it harder to figure out what needs fixing. For example, in forkJoin you are passing `apiRequest `but that doesn't exist (I imagine it should be additionalRequests). The first map right after getPagedData also doesn't return anything. I imagine it should return the result of the Observable.forkJoin call? I think replacing your first map call to switchMap/mergeMap might do what you want? It flattens observables.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct I put apiRequests when I meant additionalRequests.  Because this is a work related problem, I have to change business related variable names.  I'll give the switchMap/mergeMap a look.

Comment: I short tip (not an answer, too light for that) - check out concatMap and [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293) that shows how to use it to get page after page. In the article it is not exactly pages, but totally applicable. You need to do it one after another, only when the previous page request ended. At least this is how I understood your question.